# I don't get notifications when the application is terminated

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Notifications do show when the app is in the Foreground and Background but not when the app is terminated.

Below I have attached 3 codes in order:

- Notification logic
- Where I call the notification logic function "fetchMedicines"
- main.dart

---

The logic of my notifications work correctly, they just don't show when the application is closed (when people swipe from bottom to top they close the applications to optimize cell phone performance)

---

I am using that known package:
flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.1

1. Notifications are local.
2. The dates of the firestore data are in String format except for the Creation date, which is in timestamp format. But don't worry because I have formatted them to show notifications at the specific time and date.
   Data example:

- timeTakePill: 2023-10-04T11:52:00.000 (string)
- creationdate: 4 of October of 2023, 11:50:51 UTC-5 (timestamp)

3. Then I have a specific notification called "Once a day", it is to show the notifications every day once at the specified time "timeTakePastilla". I attach the code where the notification logic and the condition are handled once a day:

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tzdata;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

// Inicializar las zonas horarias
void initializeTimeZone() {
  tzdata.initializeTimeZones();
}

Future<tz.Location> getTimeZone() async {
  final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
  return tz.getLocation(timeZoneName);
}

int generateNotificationId(String medicineName, DateTime scheduledTime) {
  return '$medicineName${scheduledTime.hour}${scheduledTime.minute}'.hashCode;
}

void scheduleNotification(DateTime scheduledTime, String medicineName,
    String message, int notificationId) async {
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel id',
    'your channel name',
    channelDescription: 'your channel description',
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
  );

  var darwinPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails();
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: darwinPlatformChannelSpecifics);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      notificationId,
      'Tienes una medicina que tomar',
      //'Es hora de tomar $medicineName. Ya son las $time.',
      message,
      tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledTime, tz.local),
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
}

Future<void> fetchMedicines(String userId) async {
  // Obtener la zona horaria local al principio de la función
  //final tz.Location timeZone = await getTimeZone();
  QuerySnapshot medicines = await _firestore
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userId)
      .collection('medicines')
      .get();

  for (var doc in medicines.docs) {
    var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    bool? recordatorioAlarma = data['recordatorioAlarma'];
    String? nombrePastilla = data['nombrePastilla'];

    if (recordatorioAlarma == true && nombrePastilla != null) {
      if (data['frecuenciaDia'] == "Cada día" &&
          data['frecuenciaDosis'] == "Una vez al día") {
        String? horaTomarPastilla = data['horaTomarPastilla'];
        if (horaTomarPastilla != null) {
          //Fecha del campo durationSetDate
          final durationSetDateString = data['durationSetDate'] as String?;
          final DateTime? durationSetDate = durationSetDateString != null
              ? DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').parse(durationSetDateString)
              : null;
          //Fecha del campo fechaCreacion
          DateTime fechaCreacionDateTime =
              (data['fechaCreacion'] as Timestamp).toDate();
          //Si es null durationSetDate entonces usar la fecha fechaCreacionDateTime
          DateTime fechaInicio = durationSetDate ??
              DateTime(fechaCreacionDateTime.year, fechaCreacionDateTime.month,
                  fechaCreacionDateTime.day);

          
          String durationTreatment =
              (data['durationTreatment'] as String?) ?? 'Tratamiento en curso';
          int treatmentDurationDays = 0;

          if (durationTreatment.contains('día')) {
            final parts = durationTreatment.split(' ');
            treatmentDurationDays = int.tryParse(parts[0]) ?? 0;
          } else if (durationTreatment.contains('semana')) {
            treatmentDurationDays = 7;
          }

          DateTime endDateOfTreatment =
              fechaInicio.add(Duration(days: treatmentDurationDays));

          // Verificar si la fecha actual es posterior a la fecha de finalización del tratamiento
          if (DateTime.now().isAfter(endDateOfTreatment) &&
              durationTreatment != 'Tratamiento en curso') {
            // Cambiar recordatorioAlarma a false
            await doc.reference.update({'recordatorioAlarma': false});
          }
          

          DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime(
              fechaInicio.year,
              fechaInicio.month,
              fechaInicio.day,
              int.parse(horaTomarPastilla.split('T')[1].split(':')[0]),
              int.parse(horaTomarPastilla.split('T')[1].split(':')[1]));

          // Ajustar scheduledTime si es anterior a DateTime.now()
          while (scheduledTime.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
            scheduledTime = scheduledTime.add(const Duration(days: 1));
          }

          if (scheduledTime.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
            String formattedTime = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(scheduledTime);
            int notificationId =
                generateNotificationId(nombrePastilla, scheduledTime);
            String message =
                'Es hora de tomar $nombrePastilla. Ya son las $formattedTime.';
            scheduleNotification(
                scheduledTime, nombrePastilla, message, notificationId);
          }
        }
      }
```

---

4. I call the function "fetchMedicines" on a page of the application called mainpage.dart and not on main.dart

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int initialIndex;
  const MainPage({Key? key, this.initialIndex = 0}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  UserModel? currentUser;
  // 1. Inicialización del plugin de notificaciones locales
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  int selectedIndex =
      0; // Indice para controlar la navegación en la barra inferior

  Future<void> _signOut() async {
    await signOutGoogle();
    await _auth.signOut();
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      Routes.login,
      (route) => false,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // 2. Configuración de los ajustes de inicialización
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
            requestAlertPermission: true,
            requestBadgePermission: true,
            requestSoundPermission: true,
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (int id, String? title, String? body,
                String? payload) async {});

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse response) async {
      String? payload = response.payload;
      if (payload != null) {
        debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
      }
    });

    // Solicita permiso para mostrar notificaciones en Android 13+
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestPermission();
    }

    _getCurrentUser();
    selectedIndex = widget.initialIndex;

    //showTestNotification();
  }
......Other code that works on the visual scaffold side.....
```

main.dart:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/authentication/auth_google.dart';
import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/notifications/schedule_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/providers/chats_provider.dart';
//import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/providers/models_provider.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  //tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation('America/Lima'));

  // Establecer la zona horaria local del dispositivo
  final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));

  // Usa la localización actual del dispositivo
  await initializeDateFormatting();

  //DateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);

  // Cargar las variables de entorno
  // Cargar las variables de entorno
  //await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await initializeDateFormatting('es_ES', null);
  //FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

  final CallbackHandle callback =
      PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callbackDispatcher)!;
  final int callbackHandle = callback.toRawHandle();
  // Aquí puedes guardar este valor en SharedPreferences o donde prefieras.
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setInt('callback_handle', callbackHandle);

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ChatProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(), //CON ANALYTICS: child: MyApp(analytics: analytics),
    ),
  );
}

void fetchMedicinesFromBoot(List<String> args) async {
  // Aquí puedes invocar fetchMedicines con el userId que necesites.
  String? userId =
      await getUserId(); // Aquí deberías implementar la función getUserId si aún no lo has hecho.
  if (userId != null) {
    fetchMedicines(userId);
  }
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  const MethodChannel _backgroundChannel =
      MethodChannel('com.example.chatgpt_project/background_channel');
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  _backgroundChannel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
    if (call.method == 'fetchMedicinesFromBoot') {
      fetchMedicinesFromBoot([]);
    }
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key})
      : super(
            key:
                key); //CON ANALYTICS: const MyApp({Key? key, required this.analytics}) : super(key: key);

  //final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: Routes.loading,
      routes: Routes.routes,
      //navigatorObservers: [
      // FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
      //],
    );
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chatgpt_project">

   <!-- Permiso para acceder a Internet -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <!-- Permisos para las notificaciones -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

   <application
        android:label="chatgpt_project"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <!-- Receiver for handling boot completed to restore scheduled notifications after a reboot -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <!-- BootReceiver to handle re-scheduling notifications after device reboot -->
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I want to show notifications when the application is finished.

Comment: The OS itself handles closing the application on Android.  You shouldn't be doing it for them.  Trust me, the OS is aggressive about ending applications for resources.